# add a constant to each element in an NSMutableArray objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to add an integer to each elements in an NSMutableArray but could not find a way to do that. For example, trying to add 5 to an array of elements such as [3, 4, 7] to get [8,9,12].

any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the items inside are `NSNumber` objects, you can do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != arr.count ; i++) {
    NSNumber *n = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i
                   withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5 + [n intValue]]
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You loop the entire Array and replace the current object with 'object value' + 5.

```
For (int i=0, i<[myArray count], i++ {
      NSNumber *tmpNum = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];
      int tmpInt = [tmpNum intValue];
      tmpInt = tmpInt+5;
      tmpNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tmpInt];
      [myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:tmpNum];
}
```

And that should cover it.

I haven't tested this code so let me know if it's not working.
Also that's assuming the objects in your array are in NSNumber format.